# How can I remove the nodejs folder in Program Files?

Tags: node.js

I have already uninstalled nodejs, npm, and nvm. There is a folder in my Program Files called nodejs. I tried to delete it and receive the message "you require permission from administrators to make changes to this folder". When I try to reinstall nodejs, it tells me I do not have permission to make changes to the folder nodejs. How can I remove this folder so I can properly reinstall nodejs?

I have tried deleting the folder, changing the access of the folder to my user account and then deleting the folder, and using the command "rmdir C:\Program Files\nodejs".